# Why don't named pipes respect the order at which readers were attached?

Tags: fifo, mkfifo

I have this test script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

fif="foooz"; rm "$fif" ; mkfifo "$fif"

( cat "$fif" | cat && echo "1") &

sleep 0.1

( cat "$fif" | cat && echo "2") &

sleep 0.1

( cat "$fif" | cat && echo "3") &

echo "first" > "$fif"

wait;
```

the output I get is varied, I these varieties:

```
first
1
```

---

```
first
2
```

---

```
first
1
2
```

---

```
first
3
```

my question is - why doesn't the order at which readers are attached to the named pipe matter/respected? Seems lame that it's almost random?

Comment: Use tee; a pipe should only have one reader.

Comment: yeah named pipes are dumb can you show an example of using tee?

Answer (score 1):

```
F=example.fifo
mkfifo $F
cat $F | tee -a >( read B; echo "B=$B" >&2 ) >( read C; echo "C=$C" >&2 ) | (read A; echo "A=$A") &
echo OK > $F
    A=OK
    B=OK
    C=OK
rm $F
```

- ">()" is process substitution
- internal tee workings [here](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/tee.c).

Note that all 3 outputs are run at the same time (test by adding `sleep 1;`), if you want to wait for A to complete before starting B then just use a loop or list;

```
F=example.fifo
mkfifo $F
cat $F | ( read O; echo "A=$O"; echo "B=$O"; echo "C=$O") &
echo OK > $F
    A=OK
    B=OK
    C=OK
rm $F
```